# Excel Power Query and SF Connection

Tags: excel

I have Microsoft Excel 2016 installed.  It has a version of Power Query provided but it doesn't have the 'From Salesforce Objects' option from Data > Get Data > From Other Sources drop down.  When I try to install the MS-PowerQuery download add-in, it says that PowerQuery is already included and doesn't install.  Is there a way to get the Power Query SF Connection? Could it be the version of Excel?  It came with MS-Office Home subscription that came with the PC.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed the Salesforce extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Salesforce feature is only available in certain versions of Excel 2016.  They confused matters by changing the name from Power Query to "Get and Transform".  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/where-is-get-transform-power-query-e9332067-8e49-46fc-97ff-f2e1bfa0cb16

> Advanced business analytics features available with Office 365
>   ProPlus, Office 2016 Professional, Office 2016 Professional Plus, and
>   Excel 2016 standalone.